# How do I make Align.vim \adec work correctly when java generics are involved?

Tags: java, generics, vim, alignment

The Align plugin is all nice and dandy, but I encounter problems with it when dealing with generics generics such that:

```
HashMap<String, Object> session = new HashMap();
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList();
String banana = "Yo banana boy";
int count = 0;
```

After \adec it becomes:

```
HashMap<String, Object> session = new HashMap();
ArrayList<String> names                         = new ArrayList();
String banana                                   = "Yo banana boy";
int count                                       = 0;
```

But I was actually expecting:

```
HashMap<String, Object> session = new HashMap();
ArrayList<String>       names   = new ArrayList();
String                  banana  = "Yo banana boy";
int                     count   = 0;
```

or even better:

```
HashMap   <String, Object> session = new HashMap();
ArrayList <String>         names   = new ArrayList();
String                     banana  = "Yo banana boy";
int                        count   = 0;
```

How do I make Align.vim behave as described?

Comment: To be honest, I think the first one is the most readable :)

Comment: It's really a matter of preference. I like things aligned per column so that I could select related columns with visual block and do some stuff ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in Align.vim. The closest I could get was:

```
:Align < =
:Align =
```

However, to be fair, the Align.vim page on vim.org says it is for aligning C declarations. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294